# Products $s\wedge t$ generate $C_.^\infty(M,E\otimes F)$?

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, differential-forms

I am reading Demially and came upon the claim that

> for every $s\in C^\infty_.(M,E)$, $t\in C^\infty_.(M,F)$, the wedge product $s\wedge t$ can be combined with the bilinear map $E\times F\to E\otimes F$ in order to obtain a section $s\wedge t\in C^\infty_.(M,E\otimes F)$ of degree $\deg(s)+\deg(t)$.

How exactly is $s\wedge t\in C^\infty(M,E\otimes F)$ defined? I tried to define it in a local chart by $s_\alpha\wedge t_\alpha=\sum_{m,n,i,j} \sigma^i_{m\alpha}\theta^j_{n\alpha} s_{m\alpha}\otimes t_{n\alpha}\otimes(dz_{i\alpha}\wedge dz_{j\alpha})$ but couldn't verify that this section follows the transition relations of $C^\infty_.(M,E\otimes F)$.

Later on, the author claims that

> As the product $s\wedge t$ generate $C_.^\infty(M,E\otimes F)$,

I could see why on a local chart $s\wedge t$ generate $C_.^\infty(M,E\otimes F)$, but also come to difficulties as to why is it globally true. Any help?

Also, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiFUa.png) is a screen shot.

> $D_{E \otimes F}$ will be defined in such a way that the usual formula for the differentiation of a product remains valid. For every $s \in \mathscr{C}_\bullet^\infty (M,E), t \in \mathscr{C}_\bullet^\infty(M,F)$, the wedge product $s \wedge t$ can be combined with the bilinear map $E \times F \to E \otimes F$ in order to obtain a section $s \wedge t \in \mathscr{C}^\infty(M, E \otimes F)$ of degree $\deg s + \deg t$. Then there exists a unique connection $D_{E \otimes F}$ such that $$\tag{4.2} D_{E \otimes F}(s \wedge t) = D_E s \wedge t + (-1)^{\deg s} s \wedge D_F t.$$ As the products $s \wedge t$ generate $\mathscr{C}_\bullet^\infty(M, E \otimes F)$, the uniqueness is clear. If $E, F$ are...

Comment: Can you also provide the page number?

Comment: Oh, of course, its on page 257.

Comment: Things seem crazily wrong from the outset. So $s$ and $t$ are vector-bundled valued differential forms? The notation just says that they're sections of bundles. But, forgetting that, since you agree that these generate locally, can't you just glue together with partitions of unity? This is smooth, definitely not holomorphic.

Comment: Oh, the lower (big) dot is his notation for the algebra of all $E$-valued differential forms ... Not exactly standard, but OK.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that this is in the context of differentiable manifolds so one could glue things together via partitions of unity. So, I guess the second part gets settled. Any help on the first part?

Comment: Well, you certainly haven't written down a general $k$-form with values in a bundle. Remember, these are smooth differential forms, not holomorphic ones. It doesn't make much sense to write down your definition of the wedge product without first getting $s$ and $t$ defined carefully and correctly.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on a general k-form with values in a bundle?

Answer (score 1):

After thinking about what Ted Shifrin hinted, I post a tentative answer for part 1 of the question. Suppose we have $s\in C^\infty_k(M,E)$, we have the corresponding multilinear (as $C^\infty(M)$ modules) alternating functions $\eta:\mathfrak{X}(M)\times ...\times\mathfrak{X}(M)\to \Gamma(M,E)$. (Morita explains the equivalence between these two forms of differential forms with value in vector bundles in page 192 of *Geometry of Differential Forms*.) Do the same thing for $t\in C^\infty_l(M,F)$ and we have $\mu:\mathfrak{X}(M)\times ...\times\mathfrak{X}(M)\to \Gamma(M,E)$. Now observe the natural bilinear map $\beta:\Gamma(M,E)\times\Gamma(M,F)\to\Gamma(M,E)\otimes\Gamma(M,F)\cong\Gamma(M,E\otimes F)$. We now define $s\wedge t$ by defining $\eta\wedge\mu$, which is $\eta\wedge\mu(X_1,...,X_{k+l})=\frac{1}{k!l!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_{p+q}}sgn(\sigma)\beta(\eta(X_{\sigma(1)},...,X_{\sigma(k)}),\mu(X_{\sigma(k+1)},...,X_{\sigma(k+l)}))$ for $X_i\in\mathfrak{X}(M)$. This then gives a multilinear alternating function from $\mathfrak{X}(M)\times...\mathfrak{X}(M)$ to $\Gamma(M,E\otimes F)$, which correspondingly gives a section of $C^\infty_{k+l}(M,E\otimes F)$ we call $s\wedge t$. As we go back from $\eta$ to $s$ at $p\in M$, we could define $s(x_1,...,x_k)$ with $x_i\in T_pM$ as $\eta(X_1,...,X_k)(p)$ with $X_i|_p=x_i$ by a similar reasoning as Theorem 2.8 in section 2.1 of Morita. On a chart $U_\alpha$, we therefore have $s=\sum_{I,m} \sigma_{\alpha,I,m}dz_{\alpha,I}\otimes e_{\alpha,m}$ and $t=\sum_{J,n}\beta_{\alpha,J,n}dz_{\alpha,J}\otimes f_{\alpha,n}$. By definition of $\eta\wedge\mu$, we have locally $s\wedge t=\sum_{I,J,m,n}\sigma_{\alpha,I,m}\beta_{\alpha,J,n}(e_{\alpha,m}\otimes f_{\alpha,n})\otimes dz_I\wedge dz_J$.